# How to use .NET Core CLI behind a corporate proxy/firewall?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have downloaded and extracted the .NET Core SDK zipped binaries, and added them to the PATH.

I'm able to create a new console project using `dotnet new console`, but when I try to add a dependency with `dotnet add package DocumentFormat.OpenXml`, I get the following error:

```
Writing C:\Users\boobsbr\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2C7B.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' into project 'C:\projects\test\test.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\projects\test\test.csproj...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   No such host is known
```

I've read in several places that I need to add some configuration to `NuGet.config` in order to set up the HTTPS proxy. Some people recommend using `nuget.exe config -Set` in order to set the values, but the executable is not present in the binary distribution folder, and I've also read that the `dotnet.exe` uses NuGet DLLs instead of calling the `nuget.exe` executable.

So I set out to edit the file located at `C:\Users\boobsbr\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`. Some people suggest just setting the proxy URL and the user and pass would be read from some system config, so I added the following line to the config file:

`<add key="https_proxy" value="http://proxy_url:8080" />`

And this is the message I got after trying to add a package:

```
Writing C:\Users\boobsbr\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA7AF.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' into project 'C:\projects\test\test.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\projects\test\test.csproj...
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: Failed to retrieve information about 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' from remote source 'http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
error:   No such host is known
```

Alright, so I tried adding a username, as suggested by other people, and the password should be automatically picked up from some system:

```
<add key="https_proxy" value="http://proxy_url:8080" />
<add key="https_proxy.user" value="boobsbr" />
```

And this is the failure message:

```
Writing C:\Users\boobsbr\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp839E.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml' into project 'C:\projects\test\test.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\projects\test\test.csproj...
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known
info :   GET http://proxy_url:8080/FindPackagesById()?id='DocumentFormat.OpenXml'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: The local source 'C:\Users\boobsbr\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\boobsbr' doesn't exist.
```

Alright, then I tried adding a cleartext password:

```
<add key="https_proxy" value="http://proxy_url:8080" />
<add key="https_proxy.user" value="boobsbr" />
<add key="https_proxy.password" value="my_pass" />
```

And I got the same message as the previous try. I also tried using `http_proxy` instead of `https_proxy`, to no avail.

Some people say the password must be base64'd and encrypted, but the only way to do that seems to be through `nuget.exe config -Set` and I don't have `nuget.exe`.

I know the user:pass:url:port values work because I used them to get NPM talking to the NPM registry.

Maybe I'm bad at searching, but I cannot find clear documentation describing how to set up a simple configuration for a very common use case.

So, how do I configure the .NET Core CLI to use the corporate proxy/firewall?

Windwows 10 build: `15063`

.NET Core SDK version: `2.1.402`

Comment: Password for `https_proxy.password` should be encrypted. Why you didn't try to download `nuget.exe` and run `nuget.exe config -Set` just to see if it works? Also, `dotnet restore` with proxy might be broken in 2.1.402: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6978

Comment: @Peska I couldn't download it because of firewall rules, but I managed to get it from a coworker. I set the URL, user and password using `nuget config -Set` and it still didn't work. It also didn't encrypt my password in the config file.

Comment: you may want to open this as an issue at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues